# How to base64 encode /dev/random or /dev/urandom?

Tags: bash, linux, base64, uuencode, random

`cat /dev/urandom` is always a fun way to create scrolling characters on your display, but produces too many non-printable characters.

Is there an easy way to encode it on the command-line in such a way that all of its output are readable characters, base64 or uuencode for example.

Note that I prefer solutions that require no additional files to be created.

Comment: You are definitely unusual in your definition of "fun".

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What about something like

```
cat /dev/urandom | base64
```

Which gives (lots of) stuff like

```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```

Or, without the (useless) cat+pipe :

```
base64 /dev/urandom
```

*(Same kind of output ^^ )*

**EDIT :** you can also user the `--wrap` option of `base64`, to avoid having "short lines" :

```
base64 --wrap=0 /dev/urandom
```

This will remove wrapping, and you'll get "full-screen" display ^^

Comment: "All I see now is blonde, brunette, redhead."

Comment: @Stefano : so did I :-D ; 
@alexanderpas : if watching random scrolling characters makes you see that kind of characters, maybe I should watch random characters more often ^^

Comment: @alexanderpas: cat /dev/urandom | uuencode - | tr -d '0-9' | sed -e 's/\([@$&~#(?)+<>^;]\)/^[[1m^[[32m\1^[[0m/g' | sed -e 's/\([*!]\)/^[[30m\1^[[0m/g' | sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/^[[32m\1^[[0m/g' | tr -d '\n' # 1) convert ^[ to ctrl-v esc after pasting 2) can be improved, but now I'm tired ;)

Comment: `base64 --wrap=0 /dev/urandom |head -c 100` will get you 100 random base64 characters.  If you're looking for a bash-based matrix-style screen saver, [it has been done before](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10585/matrix-style) :-)

Comment: `head -c128 /dev/urandom | base64 --wrap=0`, to avoid breaking the pipe @AdamKatz.

Comment: @sebastian – True, but that shouldn't be a problem and your method requires some trial and error (or piping into another call, `head -c 100`) to get the right output character count (careful, you don't want trailing `=` characters!). Try `head -c 75 /dev/urandom |base64 -w 0` for 100 characters.

Answer (score 23):

A number of folks have suggested `cat`ting and piping through `base64` or `uuencode`. One issue with this is that you can't control how much data to read (it will continue forever, or until you hit ctrl+c). Another possibility is to use the `dd` command, which will let you specify how much data to read before exiting. For example, to read 1kb:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1k count=1 2>/dev/null | base64
```

Another option is to pipe to the `strings` command which may give more variety in its output (non-printable characters are discarded, any runs of least 4 printable characters [by default] are displayed). The problem with `strings` is that it displays each "run" on its own line.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1k count=1 2>/dev/null | strings
```

(of course you can replace the entire command with

```
strings /dev/urandom
```

if you don't want it to ever stop).

If you want something really funky, try one of:

```
cat -v /dev/urandom
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1k count=1 2>/dev/null | cat -v
```

Comment: Or `head -c 100` for instance would print the first 100 bytes of the file.

Comment: If using strings, you can also remove the newlines with an additional pipe: `strings /dev/urandom | perl -pe 's/\n//'`

Answer (score 5):

So, what is wrong with

```
cat /dev/urandom | uuencode -
```

?

Fixed after the first attempt didn't actually work... ::sigh::

BTW-- Many unix utilities use '-' in place of a filename to mean "use the standard input".

Comment: didn't know about the dash option. thanks for teaching me that ;)

Comment: (actually the dash means stdout in this case) Useless use of `cat` - do this instead: `uuencode /dev/random -`

Answer (score 4):

There are already several good answers on how to base64 encode random data (i.e. `cat /dev/urandom | base64`). However in the body of your question you elaborate:

> ... encode [urandom] on the command-line in such a way that all of it's output are readable characters, base64 or uuencode for example.

Given that you don't actually require parseable base64 and just want it to be readable, I'd suggest

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dC '[:graph:]'
```

`base64` only outputs alphanumeric characters and two symbols (+ and / by default). `[:graph:]` will match any printable non-whitespace ascii, including many symbols/punctuation-marks that base64 lacks. Therefore using `tr -dC '[:graph:]'` will result in a more random-looking output, and have better input/output efficiency.

I often use `< /dev/random stdbuf -o0 tr -Cd '[:graph:]' | stdbuf -o0 head --bytes 32` for generating strong passwords.

Comment: useless use of cat (UUoC) -- consider instead `tr -dC '[:graph:]' </dev/urandom`

Answer (score 1):

You can do more interesting stuff with BASH's FIFO pipes:

```
uuencode <(head -c 200 /dev/urandom | base64 | gzip)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9'
```

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it. It's not Base64, the conversion lack two symbols, so it's more like Base62 and thus decoded values are going to be biased, eg. not so random.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```sh
xxd -ps /dev/urandom
```

[`xxd(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd)

Comment: This will produce hexadecimal/base16 not base64